# Getting statistics from MySql using JOINED multiple tables and sub queries

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have three tables in my database which are listed below:

```
Table:           teams_info

team_id         team_name         entry_year         status 
    1                   team 1                 2015                  1
    2                   team 2                 2015                  1
    3                   team 2                 2016                  1

Table:         team_players

player_id           team_id           status           members_id       position 
       1                     1                      0                       1                      1
       2                     1                      1                       2                      2
       3                     1                      1                       3                      3
       4                     1                      1                       4                      4
       5                     2                      0                       5                      1
       6                     2                      0                       6                      2
       7                     2                      1                       7                      3

Table:          members

members_id           first_name           surname            gender
       1                  joe                  blogg                 male
       2                  james                smith                 male
       3                  sarah                marshall             female
       4                  tony                 walker                 male
       5                  peter                jones                 male
       6                  jessica              varley                 female
       7                 jane                  varley                 female
```

I'm trying to get my head around how I would get the following information,

1) How many team_players from team_info.entry_year = 2015  have accepted the to join a team (this will be all players with status = 1)

2) How many team_players from team_info.entry_year = 2015 have been invited (basically counting all records that belong to 2015 teams in table team_info)

3) The total Males players from 2015 teams.

4) The total female players from 2015 teams.

I'm fairly new to SQL and it seems I have made things complicated whilst trying to follow the best standards, however I can't wrap my head around where to start.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I can only see a specification, but there is no question. You also need to demonstrate what you have done to solve the question. At the moment it feels that you would like us to solve your homework for you. Such topics do not really fly well here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using mysql or some other RDBMS?

I'll assume mysql here, as there are a variety of join syntaxes you can use and they vary by database.

What you want to do here is do an INNER join of all 3 tables which will give you one row per intersection.

Fortunately, you have a good basic normalized structure that has separated the TEAM entity from the MEMBERS (players).

Because your app supports "seasons" you have a good many-to-many resolver table in team_players.

So, to join the tables together, strictly speaking it doesn't really matter which table you start with, but in a case like this, I will start with the many to many resolution table:
SELECT *

```
FROM team_players as tp LEFT JOIN teams_info as ti ON (ti.team_id = tp.team_id) LEFT JOIN members as m ON (m.members_id = tp.members_id) At this point, you are inner joining and should have 1 row essentially for every match, which is going to be one row for every row in team_players.
```

In your examples, you want a count, so rather than SELECT *, you just want COUNT(*) as 'some_name'.  What you alias that name to be is up to you.  For example you could have:

```
SELECT count(*) as accepted_in_2015
FROM team_players as tp
LEFT JOIN teams_info as ti ON (ti.team_id = tp.team_id)
LEFT JOIN members as m ON (m.members_id = tp.members_id)
```

Of course, what is missing now is the filtration.  You can add these with a WHERE clause in most cases, but I typically add them in the appropriate join criteria.  So when I'm adding a WHERE/filtration criteria that has to do with a team, I will put it in the ON that involves the teams_info join.

Where it's a 'member' table criteria (status in your first question) I add that there.

So to answer your first question, this should probably work:

> 1) How many team_players from team_info.entry_year = 2015 
>   have accepted the to join a team (this will be all players with status
>   = 1)

```
SELECT count(*) as accepted_in_2015
FROM team_players as tp
LEFT JOIN teams_info as ti ON (ti.team_id = tp.team_id AND ti.entry_year = 2015)
LEFT JOIN members as m ON (m.members_id = tp.members_id AND m.status = 1)
```

The other questions are all variations on this same blue print and can be determined the same way, however, in the case of male/female I'd probably just group by and get counts for male vs/ female in one query.